# PDF Viewer via Pdf-Reader---Writer in Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, pdf-viewer

I have to implement PDF viewer library in project I am following https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer/blob/master/Pdf_%20Reader_Writer/README.md
In this example they are creating PDF and loading in viewer. 
Actually I understood how library works Here is the below snippet of code for creating and loading PDF from library:

```
            @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
    String pdfcontent = generateHelloWorldPDF(); //generating pdf content
    outputToFile("PdfSample.pdf",pdfcontent,"ISO-8859-1"); //passing pdf name and content
        return null;
    }

          private String generateHelloWorldPDF() 
          { //function returns pdf content with pages
        PDFWriter mPDFWriter = new PDFWriter(PaperSize.FOLIO_WIDTH, PaperSize.FOLIO_HEIGHT);


    try {
        // all image formates are supported
        Bitmap i1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);   
        mPDFWriter.addImage(40, 60, i1, Transformation.DEGREES_315_ROTATION);
        mPDFWriter.addImage(72, 72, i1);
        mPDFWriter.addImage(200, 400, 135, 75, i1);
        mPDFWriter.addImage(150, 300, 130, 70, i1);
        mPDFWriter.addImageKeepRatio(100, 200, 50, 25, i1);
        mPDFWriter.addImageKeepRatio(50, 100, 30, 25, i1, Transformation.DEGREES_270_ROTATION);
        mPDFWriter.addImageKeepRatio(25, 50, 30, 25, i1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
    mPDFWriter.addRawContent("row content \n");
    mPDFWriter.addText(70, 50, 12, "hello world");
    mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
    mPDFWriter.addRawContent("row content rg\n");
    mPDFWriter.addText(30, 90, 10, "ï¿½ CRL", Transformation.DEGREES_270_ROTATION);

    mPDFWriter.newPage();
    mPDFWriter.addRawContent("[] 0 d\n");
    mPDFWriter.addRawContent("1 w\n");
    mPDFWriter.addRawContent("0 0 1 RG\n");
    mPDFWriter.addRawContent("0 1 0 rg\n");
    mPDFWriter.addRectangle(40, 50, 280, 50);
    mPDFWriter.addText(85, 75, 18, "Android Docs");

    mPDFWriter.newPage();
    mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER_BOLD);
   // mPDFWriter.addText(150, 150, 14, "http://coderesearchlabs.com");
    mPDFWriter.addLine(150, 140, 300, 140);

    String s = mPDFWriter.asString();
    return s;
}


         private void outputToFile(String fileName, String pdfContent, String encoding)        { //function which pushes the file to below path
    //System.out.println("content" +fileName);
   if(isSDPresent)
   {

       try {
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pdf_Writer_Reader/");
                if (!dir.exists())
                {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                newFile = new File(dir,fileName);
                if(!newFile.exists())
                {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                }

               try
               {
                    FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                    pdfFile.write(pdfContent.getBytes(encoding));               
                    pdfFile.close();
               }
               catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("Ex==",""+e.toString());
               }
       } 
       catch(IOException e)
       {
        Log.e("Ex==",""+e.toString());
       }
   }
```

can anybody suggest on how to load PDF from sdcard any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project you mentioned on GitHub is based on [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com) library. In the same GitHub project you have an example of reading a pdf in an Activity -  [MuPDFActivity](https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer/blob/master/Pdf_%20Reader_Writer/src/com/artifex/mupdf/MuPDFActivity.java) The part of the Activity which reads the PDF is at the start -

```
private MuPDFCore openFile(String path)
{
    int lastSlashPos = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    mFileName = new String(lastSlashPos == -1? path : path.substring(lastSlashPos+1));
    System.out.println("Trying to open "+path);
    try
    {
        core = new MuPDFCore(path);
        // New file: drop the old outline data
        OutlineActivityData.set(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    return core;
}
```

Using the MuPDFCore instance you call

```
    public static native void drawPage(Bitmap bitmap, int pageW, int pageH, 
int patchX, int patchY,
int patchW, int patchH);
```

to write the particular page on the bitmap. To know more check the project which has a working sample to display pdfs.

Comment: so i have pass path to openFile method in ChoosePDFActivity background method

Comment: You can use the `openFile()` method in any Activity

Comment: then what is the use of drawPage why should we use that..?

Comment: @ asloob i given path to openFile but file is crashing    activity.openFile("/mnt/sdcard/pdf_Writer_Reader/TheAccidentalBully.pdf");

Comment: @user1048958 Please mark the answer as correct so that others can know that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

//comment your openFile(String path) function and replace below code ...

```
private MuPDFCore openFile()
{
    String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    File path, file;
    MuPDFCore core;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(storageState))
    {
        System.out.println("Media mounted read/write");
    }
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(storageState))
    {
        System.out.println("Media mounted read only");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No media at all! Bale!\n");
        return null;
    }
    path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    file = new File(path, "TheAccidentalBully.pdf");
    System.out.println("Trying to open "+file.toString());
    try
    {
        core = new MuPDFCore(file.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    return core;
}

         and onCreate

           if (core == null) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            core = openFile();
            SearchTaskResult.set(null);
        }
```

Comment: @asloob it is possible to highlight text and on touch show meaning of the text on that pdf which we are viewing...

Comment: The edits you have made are to check whether media is mounted. And you have hardcoded the name of the file to open. IMO these are secondary things and can be avoided. The crux of the answer is already given. Still you can keep your answer for others reference.